# Showing up the image through code behind

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a sitecore control like this: `<sc:Image ID="imgLogo" runat="server" Field="Image"/>`

Now the current item does not have an Image field. I am pulling the Item through droptree in CurrentItem like this (**GetFieldValue** is same as GetField. I am overriding the base class in Sitecore):

```
 string countryGuid = CurrentItem.GetFieldValue("Country", null); 
 Item country = sitecoreDatabase.GetItem(countryGuid);
 BindCountryLogo();
```

Now in this `Item` I have an image for the country logo. All I want to show up on the sc:Image.

So far I got this:

```
 private void BindCountryLogo(Item country)
    {
        Fields.ImageField logoField = country.Fields["Image"];
        if (logoField != null && logoField.MediaItem != null)
        {
            //Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem image = new MediaItem(logoField.MediaItem);
            //string src = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(image);
            //imgLogo.DataSource = src;
            //imgLogo.ImageUrl = logoField.MediaItem.Source.;
            //string src = Sitecore.StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/', Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(logoField));
            //Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem img = new MediaItem(ImageField.Medi)
        }
     }
```

None of them are working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The  control has a property "Item" which you can set to the item that holds the imageField.

Your BindCountryLogo should look like this:

```
private void BindCountryLogo(Item country)
{
    imgLogo.Item = country;    
}
```

(Or remove the BindCountryLogo() method and set the Item in the main method ;) )